# AngularJS $http with jQuery plugin (Mixitup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in my application to request some data:

```
$http.get(cmsUrl + "/city_guides/index.json").success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.city_guides = data;
});
```

Now, with my city_guides variable, populate my view with the data.

```
div#MixItUpContainer1(mix-it-up)
            .mix.category-nature(ng-repeat="cityguide in city_guides")
                span.arrow
                img(src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/sports/", alt="")
                div.details
                    p.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Now, i'll init the mixitup jquery plugin.

```
superLegalApp.directive('mixItUp', ['$compile', '$timeout', function($compile, $timeout) {

return {
   restrict: 'AE',
   replace: false,
   link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

       $timeout(function() {
          $(elem).mixItUp();
       });
   }
 }
    }]);
```

As you can see, i do this with angular directives.

But the Mixitup adds an "fail" class to my object.

How can i fix this? Very thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with jQuery MixItUp in AngularJS.

I managed to integrate the plugin by using AngularJS function `$rootScope.$broadcast`.

Once all data from `$http` is loaded i trigger MixItUp by calling:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('init-mixitup');
```

Here is my directive where i listen to this event:

```
myApp
.directive('mixitup', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$on('init-mixitup', function(event) {
                console.log('init');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp({
                    animation: {
                        duration: 200
                    },
                    load: {
                        sort: 'myorder:desc'
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can see the full issue here: [Integrating jQuery MixItUp in an angular.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290080/integrating-jquery-mixitup-in-an-angular-js-project/)